# Apache service is not able to start and gives the Error 1053

Tags: windows-services, tomcat8, apache2.4

I am trying to access my application through web but it gives the following error:

[Web Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMYDy.png)

But it is accessible through the Windows Client app.

- So this issue is related to the Application server "Apache", it looks like that the Apache service has stopped suddenly and when I tried to start the service it gives the below error:

[Apache Service Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PK5X.png)

I checked the Apache error logs and found the following:

[Mon Jul 26 13:48:40.183080 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1332:tid 460] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.

[Mon Jul 26 13:48:42.464337 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1552:tid 348] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.

[Mon Jul 26 13:48:49.323735 2021] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1332:tid 460] AH00430: Parent: Child process 1552 exited successfully.

- Same issue exists for Tomcat 8.0 service, it seems it stopped suddenly and
  when I try to start the service it gives the below error:

[Tomcat Service Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gejQi.png)

in the log file:
"
2021-07-26 13:52:21 Commons Daemon procrun stdout initialized
".

Note that:

- the Apache Application server here works as a reverse proxy only.
- IIS service is not installed in the server.

Comment: Hello Anas, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't include the errors as images whenever possible (`Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V` usually also works in Windows dialog windows). Also please split the two problems you encounter into two questions (e.g. post another question for Tomcat): these two problems might require two different experts.

Comment: Regarding Apache, please include a larger sample of the logs: what caused Apache to shut down?